# How to calculate NSMutableAttributedString height correctly?

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

I have tried two methods:

**attrString** is `NSMutableAttributedString`

1.

```objectivec
CGRect rect = [attrString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(contentWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading context:nil];
```

2. 

```objectivec
NSTextStorage *textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:attrString];
NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(contentWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
[layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];
[textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];
[layoutManager glyphRangeForTextContainer:textContainer];
CGRect rect = [layoutManager usedRectForTextContainer:textContainer];
```

But neither are right height.

Here is the demo :[AttrStringDemo](https://github.com/magic3584/AttrStringDemo)

Comment: “But neither are right height.” Really? Prove it, please. Give an actual example.

Comment: @matt Hi, I have uploaded a demo here :[AttrStringDemo](https://github.com/magic3584/AttrStringDemo)

Answer (score 0):

I **plus 1** to height after calculated the rect, it works.